# Are questions about the hypothetical effects of a policy on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Why don't we pay food stamps and unemployment benefits indefinitely to stimulate the economy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/1653/169)

This question is asking why we do not change the policy to widen the effects that are seen.

We can only hypothesize what the answer would be.  So are these types of questions on topic?

I do not think these are necessarily asking for opinions since you could in theory make a constructive fact based  answer to this.

Comment: This is a great question.  I'm not sure I agree with your answer, but not sure I disagree either.  I'd love to see some answers first :)

Comment: @AffableGeek - I haven't posted an answer.  Like you I am not sure.  I think most answers that question will get will be opinion but that is a problem of the person answering rather than the question.  But that is why I think it needs to be answered here

Comment: "I do not think these are necessarily asking for opinions since you could in theory make a constructive fact based answer to this."

Comment: But I agree, this is a great question!

Comment: I'd vote 'no' for for the reason that there is no easily discernable 'right' answer, so makes it less suited to the SE format.

Comment: @AffableGeek and chad: I took a stab at answering it. I'll leave it up to you two as to whether or not it was more factual or opinion based (I'm leaning towards the latter)

Comment: @DA FWIW I think that is probably as close to a fact based answer as is likely to be seen.

Comment: This question is not about the hypothetical effects of a policy - it is about the reasons why a policy is (or is not) adopted.

Comment: @DJClayworth I think it's about the hypothetical reasons why a policy is not proposed. (as far as I know, no one has ever formally proposed that every citizen should get food stamps, for example)

Comment: There may be *actual* reasons why a policy is not proposed. I don't think the question is about giving food stamps to everyone, but about continuing benefits paid during a slowdown after the slowdown finishes.

Comment: Interestingly the result is 0 net votes for on topic and 1 vote against off topic...

Answer (score 1):

They should be on topic.

You can definitely make a constructive answer - there are economics projection studies done on those topics all the time.

Granted, some answers may be subjective, but that's what voting's for.

Comment: @Chad - if the question is about politics, AND can be answered constructively, it should be on topic.

Answer (score 0):

They should be off topic.

Despite the potential for a constructive answer they are more likely to spawn answers that result in commentary and opinion than objective and well referenced answers.  Because it is hypothetical valid arguments can be made for using conjecture or assumptions that may not be valid, or accurate.  For example with the question here there is an assumption that the improvement to the economy will be linear based on the amount of money put into the program.

Comment: We can treat those answers like we do on skeptics. Answers without citations should be ignored or downvoted.

Comment: @Avi - The problem is even on skeptics answers that are popular but bad get upvotes.  But the point of this question was to decide if the community wanted to have discussion about hypothetical situations and the answer appears to be yes they do.

Comment: that's good. I don't think we can really solve the problem of bad answers sometimes getting upvotes. I'm not sure I could find a StackExchange site where that didn't happen sometimes.

Comment: @Avi  - Because there is alot of good that can come from a question like: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/what-are-the-benefits-drawbacks-of-a-weighted-vote-based-upon-federal-taxes-paid

Comment: So far, all answers to that question have negative votes. I'm not sure what good you're expecting.

Comment: @Avi - I think the questions are broken windows that do more harm than any possible good answer can remedy

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this fall into the category of discussion topics, and are quite rarely concrete questions.

Comment: Examples please?