# Are questions about implausible hypothetical situations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Specific example: [What would happen if no one voted in the next General Election?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/19352/11249)

On one hand it's about a political process and could be considered on-topic.

On the other hand, it's an extremely implausible hypothetical scenario, and not a very "useful" question, as such.

Should this question – and those like it – be considered on-topic?

---

Some previous related discussions:

- [Are questions about the hypothetical effects of a policy on topic?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1366/11249)
- [Can we create a tag about hypothetical scenarios about things that didn't happen?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2654/11249)
- [Theoretical Questions are Broad or Opinion-Based?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2806/11249)

Answer (score 5):

Unlikely hypothetical questions can also be on topic, even if they are almost sure not to happen, because they can help elucidate the principles behind a subject area.

Also, there is no harm in someone answering an answerable question, and there is no harm in a question not being answered if no one is bothered to do so.

In general, there should be a strong presumption against closing a question unless there is clearly no other good alternative.

Also, strange things do happen. While it may be unlikely that no one votes in a national election for Congress, if one of the offices contested in an election is a special district bond issue, or a race for city council in a city with a population of 23, or a school board race in hamlet with a one room school, the question can and does come up. Indeed, one of the criteria that Colorado law used to determine when a local government charter should be revoked is that it has had multiple general elections in which no one voted. Several local governments every election cycle cease to be as a result of that law.

Comment: Overall a good answer, but I don't agree with the second paragraph. People come to this site for two reasons: 1) to ask questions, and 2) to find and answer interesting questions. A significant number of "bad" questions would be off-putting for those people (there is a saying in Dutch: "one fool can ask more questions than ten wise men can answer").